# SwiftUI: How do I get my TextField to be editable?

Tags: textfield, swiftui, xcode11

I have a "card" view that can be swiped left or right which contains a TextField. However, the TextField is not allowing me to edit it. I do not understand this. Every tutorial I see, the TextField edits with no issue. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I've figured out that the TextField is being used as part of the gesture recognition. I can drag on the TextField and it will move the whole card. How do I make the textfield not draggable yet remain part of the card and drag when the image is dragged?

```
            return VStack {
                Image("food")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50))
                TextField("Leave a comment", text: $comment) {
                    self.commentText = self.comment
                }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0), cornerRadius: 10.0)
            }
                .padding()
                .shadow(color: Color.black, radius: 15, x: 2, y: 2)
                .offset(
                    x: viewState.width + dragState.translation.width
                )
                .gesture(longPressDrag)
                .presentation($showAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text("User commented on this photo!"), message: Text(commentText), primaryButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
                            self.viewState = CGSize.zero
                        }, secondaryButton: .cancel()
                    )
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my edits for a better code sample and explanation of what I figured out it is doing.

Comment: did you yet find a solution for your problem?